# Close a cursor in indexeddb with javascript

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Is there way to close all cursors in an indexeddb?
I need to stop all the currently open cursors using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IndexedDB has a transactional model which means that each database object like table, cursor, index can be accessed in a transaction scope. They cannot be opened or accessed outside a transaction.

[Check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB)

> IndexedDB is built on a transactional database model. Everything you
>   do in IndexedDB always happens in the context of a transaction. The
>   IndexedDB API provides lots of objects that represent indexes, tables,
>   cursors, and so on, but each of these is tied to a particular
>   transaction. Thus, you cannot execute commands or open cursors outside
>   of a transaction.

So, like opening a cursor, a cursor can only be closed from the its transaction context. Hence you cannot close ALL opened cursor on IndexedDB from a single API call. There is no such API available for IndexedDB.